# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, webpack, gulp

From researching BLE Beacons I have came across Hacktimote Project. Cloning, updating dependencies, and running, I have came across this error:

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string

I have narrowed this error down to:

```
    module.exports = {

  output: {

    path: path.join(__dirname, 'www'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[chunkhash].js'
```

When placing `publicPath: '',`

the project runs, however, nothing displays on the webpage.

App has been developed with:

Angularjs, ionic-sdk, webpack, gulp and cordova plugins

The link to the repo is:

https://github.com/Hacktimote/SlackBooking/tree/master/client

Answer (score 2):

Can you replace and check

```
 path: path.join(__dirname, 'www')
```

to

```
 path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'www'),
```